# Flutter - How to implement multiple checkboxes with a "SelectAll"?

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, state

Minimal Reproducible Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  bool isSelectAll = false;
  //bool isChecked = false;

  List<bool> isCheckedList = List.generate(10, (index) => false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Checkbox(
                value: isSelectAll,
                onChanged: (checked) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      isSelectAll = checked!;
                    },
                  );
                }),
            Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return ExpansionTile(
                    title: const Text('sample'),
                    leading: Checkbox(
                        value: isCheckedList[index],
                        onChanged: (checked) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              // if (isSelectAll == true) {
                              //   checked = true;
                              // }
                              isCheckedList[index] =
                                  (isSelectAll == true) ? true : checked!;
                              //_title = _getTitle();
                            },
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                }),
                itemCount: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Selecting the top checkbox should select all the checkboxes. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) there are missing snippet here.

Comment: I have added all the required code now

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop here,  or methods like `map`, `fillRange`.

```dart
Checkbox(
    value: isSelectAll,
    onChanged: (checked) {
      if (checked == true) {
         // isCheckedList = isCheckedList.map((e) => true).toList();
         isCheckedList.fillRange(0, isCheckedList.length, true);
        isSelectAll = true;
      } else {
        isCheckedList.fillRange(0, isCheckedList.length, true);
      }
      setState(() {});
    }),
```